# xxxxx@21cn.com email login to Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a mobile app using Firebase and its email authentication feature. I found that there are some unknown sign up with email with 21cn.com domain even though I'm not publishing the app yet. It seems like these email addresses are related to this website(https://mail.21cn.com/w2/).

[image]

Is there a way to prevent these unknown signup from outside or how can I improve the project safety?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking around even in my projects and it is not possible to audit who and/or how added the accounts for Firebase Auth (not even in the Activity logs in the GCP Project associated with your Firebase Project)

So, if you don’t know those accounts, I’d suggest deleting them. Also, if the app is not yet published, maybe someone else (if more users are implied in the project) added those accounts directly to Firebase Auth.

Also you may want to change the password of your account.

In general the security of the Firebase Console is up to you.